# Dynamically changing a keyframes time attribute in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, timeline, keyframe

I am making a game in JavaFX and have implemented a slider for controlling the game speed. I have a simple slider (javafx.scene.control.Slider) and I'm binding the time attribute for the gameloop to the value I get from the slider.

The slider only really works when increasing the gamespeed. If i decrease it, the gameUpdate() will stop for a while - dependent on how much i decease it. If i increase the slider while waiting for the game to catch up, the game will continue again. Sometimes the game doesn't seem to catch up at all no matter how long i wait.

Is changing the keyframe time a bad idea in general or am i forgetting something else?
I have been trying out changing the canSkip variable, and that seems to get the game running smoother when it starts again, but does not help me much.

```
def gameLoop:Timeline = Timeline{
    repeatCount: Timeline.INDEFINITE
    keyFrames: [
        KeyFrame{
            time: bind Duration.valueOf(Config.REFRESH_RATE_NUMBER - gameSpeed)
            action: function(){
                gameUpdate();
            }
        }
    ]//keyFrames[]
}// Timeline{}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a situation rather similar to this (although in JavaFX 1.1.1), which I reported in [JIRA](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-4854)

I found that this was solved if I moved the declaration from script level - in my case this was into an initialisation function (not init{} block).

However I would agree that changing the keyframe time dynamically is a bad idea.
The use of "subtimelines" in the snippet you have posted is apparently not supported, and instead the recommended solution is to use the JavaFX 1.2 [SequentialTransition](http://java.sun.com/javafx/1.2/docs/api/javafx.animation.transition/javafx.animation.transition.SequentialTransition.html) and [ParallelTransition](http://java.sun.com/javafx/1.2/docs/api/javafx.animation.transition/javafx.animation.transition.ParallelTransition.html) timelines.

Read the JIRA bug report for more info and please post back if it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Unless i have mistunderstood (which happens all the time), I don't use any subtimelines in my snippet. Isn't subtimelines timelines inside keyframes in the original timeline? And as far as i can see, those parts of the code you posted on JIRA shouldn't really affect the time altering anyway. The time bound to a changing variable seems to be the problem still. I couldn't get it to work when moving the declaration either. Did you move it outside the whole script?

Comment: I was hoping that the bug report would give you some pointers rather than be a direct solution.  To move forward, is there any way you can try using the *Transition classes instead?  I did find this area to be rather buggy when I tried, so maybe you could try raising in JIRA if you still have no success?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest generating a sequence of keyframes in a function, then deleting and re-setting the keyframes. With the bind it seems it might try to adjust the timeline while the user is dragging the slider.